# Anno Domini calendar to Buddhist calendar primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

Can I change year in calendar from A.D. to B.E. in primefaces 3.5

Comment: Have you tried anything..?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you're trying to do. Are you converting from AD on the server side to BE on the client side, or vice versa, or do you want it all to occur on one side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once used JQuery datepicker with BE calendar and i used https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-datepicker-extension-buddhist-era/ 
and because primefaces does use JQuery datepicker try to include this extension after jquery and add in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".datepicker").datepicker({                
                isBE: true,
                autoConversionField: true
});
});
</script>
```

This should do the trick.